# Simplification of trig(arctrig()) expressions like $\sin(2\arcsin(x))$ or $\sec(\arctan(x))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

Doing integration practice, I've seen lots of cases where I end up with expressions like $\sin(2\arcsin(x))$ or $\sec(\arctan(x))$. Checking integral-calculator.com, it turns out that these expressions simplify to:

$\sin(2\arcsin(x)) = 2x \sqrt{1-x^2}$
$\sec(\arctan(x)) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$

There are many other examples such as $\sin(\sec^{-1}(x))$, $\tan(\sec^{-1}(x))$, etc.

How are these kinds of expressions generally simplified? Is there a general method?

Thanks!

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zud3aCeSLRs)

Comment: You might find the phrase "reference triangle" helpful

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Tony Mathew's and Accelerator's suggestions, you can draw a unit triangle with sides $x$ and $\sqrt {1-x^2}$ and hypotenuse $1$, and then use that triangle to determine the other functions.

For instance, to find $\sin(2\arcsin x)$, $\cos \theta = \frac {\sqrt {1-x^2}} {1} = {\sqrt {1-x^2}}$, and then $\sin \theta = \frac {x}{1} = x$.  Then you can use the substitution $\theta = \arcsin x$ (noting the range of $\arcsin x$) and the identity for $\sin 2\theta$ to obtain your answer.

This method will also work for the two other functions you've listed, but you might have to use a little algebra to get to the final result.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend defining a new variable like $\theta$ for the arc trig expressions, expanding out the trig formula in terms of simple $\theta$ (rather than multiples), and substitute back.

For example, $\sin(2 \sin^{-1}(x))$
\begin{align}
   \theta &\equiv \sin^{-1}(x) \\
   \sin(2 \sin^{-1}(x)) &= \sin 2\theta = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \\
   \sin \theta &= x, \; \cos \theta = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{1 - x^2} \\
   \implies& \sin(2 \sin^{-1}(x)) = 2 x \sqrt{1 - x^2} 
\end{align}

Comment: The assertion that $\cos\theta = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}$ depends on the range of the arcsine function, which you have not stated.

Comment: If the range isn't specified then there is not just one formula for $\sin(2\arcsin x)$